# Unable to call method multiple times in tapestry/html

Tags: javascript, html, tapestry

I am trying to call a task(method in java) based on a condition in tapestry.

I get the below error:

```
[6/17/23 2:50:17:541 UTC] 0000001d TaskEngine    E au.com.aiaa.navigation.task.TaskEngine activateExceptionPage Exception. Logged in user: Unknown, exception page activated from page: au.com.aiaa.claims.web.viewclaim.ViewClaimPage$Enhance_32@6ff66ff6[ViewClaimPage]
                                 org.apache.tapestry.ApplicationRuntimeException: Template for component ViewRequirementRetailDetailsPage contains multiple references to embedded component startCancelRequirementTask.
        at org.apache.tapestry.BaseComponentTemplateLoader.process(BaseComponentTemplateLoader.java:243)
```

This task should not be applicable in all scenarios. I added the below condition

```
<if jwcid = "isFSCIPOnly">
      <td><submit id="startCancelRequirementTask" jwcid="startCancelRequirementTask"/></td>
    </if>
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
   <if jwcid ="isFSC">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <if jwcid = "isFSCIPOnly">
      <td><submit id="startCancelRequirementTask" jwcid="startCancelRequirementTask"/></td>
    </if>                
    </if>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><submit id="startCancelRequirementTask" jwcid="startCancelRequirementTask"/></td>
```

How can I refer to this task multiple times?.

Regards
R

Comment: Appears to be a version of Tapestry prior to release 5.0 (which was back in 2008). Can you let us know which version it actually is?